# get all handles

Tags: winapi, handle

How can I get all handles of a window via Win32? I found this code but I don't know how is it work!

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
  [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
  static extern bool EnumChildWindows(IntPtr hwndParent, EnumWindowsProc lpEnumFunc,   IntPtr lParam);

  private List<IntPtr> GetChildWindows(IntPtr parent)  
  {  
    List<IntPtr> result = new List<IntPtr>();  
    GCHandle listHandle = GCHandle.Alloc(result);  
    try  
    {  
         EnumWindowProc childProc = new EnumWindowProc(EnumWindow);  
         EnumChildWindows(parent, childProc, GCHandle.ToIntPtr(listHandle));  
    }  
    finally  
    {  
         if (listHandle.IsAllocated)  
               listHandle.Free();  
    }  
    return result;  
   }
```

Comment: You can understand that by reading the Win32 documentation.

Comment: The posted code is incomplete and buggy.  Write your own, best way to also understand it.

Comment: Your question is unclear. What handles are you looking for? Try to describe exactly what you are trying to achieve. Also, your question is tagged `winapi`. That usually implies `c` or `c++`. However, the code you presented is written in `c#`. You should probably also re-tag your question and include `pinvoke` (or whichever interop-procedure you favor) in addition to the language.

Comment: @Tim winapi certainly does not imply C or C++. It implies Win32 which is accessible from hundreds of different languages.

Comment: @David Win32 is exposed as a C API. So naturally any language that can consume a C interface is capable of using Win32. However, if a question is tagged `winapi` without any language tags it implies a C solution. Which does not coincide with the code posted in the question. Hence my comment to update the tags appropriately.